# Multiple matches with re in Python

Tags: python, string, list, cpu-word, python-re

I am developing a program and I need help to match the existing word from list. ***What I am trying to do is find the number in front of the words in list. But list has multiple words. The program should try the words until it finds out the number.*** I've tried this but didn't help me. Please help.

Code:

```
import re
time = ['o\'clock', 'o clock']

# If str == 'reminder at 17 o'clock
# Program finds 17
# But if str equals this:

str = 'reminder at 17 o clock'
for a in time:
    gettime = re.findall(fr'(\b\d+\b) {a}', str)
    gettime ''.join(gettime)
    gettime = int(gettime)

print(gettime)
```

The code gives error, which is `Invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

How to run this program for these two words. `o'clock` and `o clock`

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be because you're using dangerous variable names like `str` (which is a built-in function) and `time` (which is a useful built-in module, even though you may not have imported it, still not a good idea)

Comment: It's just an example, not my real code. I know they're built-in functions. I hurriedly wrote that names.

Comment: that's ok-- but in the future you should copy/paste functioning code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample may give the result you expect:

```
import re
time = ['o\'clock', 'o clock']

# If str == 'reminder at 17 o'clock
# Program finds 17
# But if str equals this:

str = "reminder at 17 o'clock or 18 o clock"
times = []
for a in time:
    result = re.findall(fr'(\b\d+\b) {a}', str)
    #print(result)
    for i in result:
        itime = int(i)
        times.append(itime)

print(times)
```

This should display:

```
[17, 18]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really working! If you are interested in making AI Voice Assistant, I'm developing it. And I asked this question because I am developing reminder app for assistant. If you want to join as volunteer, please DM me on Instagram. id: @ugurokuduro